# Creating tables with borders in IEEE conference two column format

Tags: tables, two-column, ieeetran

I'm new to LaTex. I'm trying to find some sample code that shows how to create a single column table with borders (and if possible a grey header row) in a two column paper.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I suggest you look at http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=widefigs and http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=destable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you mentioned IEEE, in these documentclass(es) the starred versions of `table` and `figure` span the whole page.

To have a highlighted (colored) line, just add `rowcolor{your_favorite_color}` before the line in question. To make this available, you need to load the `colortbl` and the (`xcolor` or `color`) packages in the preamble.

In my example the `lipsum` package is just necessary to generate some random text.

Here's a MWE you can try (I kept the title and author info from the downloadable template):

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{xcolor}% you could also use the color package
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Conferences}

\author{\authorblockN{Michael Shell}
\authorblockA{School of Electrical and\\Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology\\
Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250\\
Email: mshell@ece.gatech.edu}
\and
\authorblockN{Homer Simpson}
\authorblockA{Twentieth Century Fox\\
Springfield, USA\\
Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
\and
\authorblockN{James Kirk\\ and Montgomery Scott}
\authorblockA{Starfleet Academy\\
San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\
Telephone: (800) 555--1212\\
Fax: (888) 555--1212}}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\section{Table Example}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray}
A & B & C\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[2-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: MWE... done! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{xcolor}% enables use of color package
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Conferences}

\author{Aswani~Kumar~Eedara}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract goes here.
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\section{ Table spanning two columns of the paper in center}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c||c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray}
A & B & C & D & E & F\\    \hline
A & B & C & D & E & F\\    \hline
A & B & C & D & E & F\\    \hline
A & B & C & D & E & F\\    \hline
A & B & C & D & E & F\\    \hline
A & B & C & D & E & F\\    \hline
A & B & C & D & E & F\\    \hline
A & B & C & D & E & F\\    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\lipsum[2-10]%

\section{ Table spanning in single column of the paper in center}
\lipsum[11-30]
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor{yellow}
A & B & C\\    \hline%hline draws horizontal line
1 & 2 & 3\\    
1 & 2 & 3\\    \hline
1 & 2 & 3\\    \hline
1 & 2 & 3\\    \hline
1 & 2 & 3\\    \hline
1 & 2 & 3\\    \hline
1 & 2 & 3\\    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum[16-50]

\end{document}
```

Comment: How is this different to the existing answer?